# System.out.println and String arguments

Tags: java, println

When I write:

```
System.out.println("Give grade: ", args[0]);
```

It gives the error:

> The method println(String) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String).

Why is this so? However, when I try to write

```
System.out.println("Give grade :");
System.out.println(args[0]);
```

No error shows. Is there a way I can write the above in one line of `println()`?

Comment: Where else have you looked for an answer?

Comment: I would vote up for this question since it showed the OP's thinking process and the effort to make it work before asking questions here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two that work only take one parameter, the one that fails takes two. Any chance you have a Javascript or Python background? Java enforces parameter type and count (like C).

Try

`System.out.println("Give grade: " + args[0]);`

or

`System.out.printf("Give grade: %s%n", args[0]);`

Comment: did you mean `\n`, not `%n`?

Comment: Nope. `%n` uses `System.lineSeparator()`, so it's Windows-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

One line. This just does the string concatenation inline.

```
System.out.println("Give grade: "+ args[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`PrintWriter#println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println-java.lang.String-) javadoc, it notes that it takes a single argument.

You can, instead, concatenate the data to form a single `String` parameter:

```
System.out.println("Give grade: " + args[0]);
```

You may want to check [`PrintWriter#printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

```
System.out.printf("Give grade: %s\n", args[0]);
```

Note that the method above is available since Java 5 (but surely you're using Java 7 or 8).

Answer (score 1):

Another method that you can use is `format`. It takes any number of arguments and formats them in various ways. The patterns should be familiar to you from other languages, they are pretty standard.

```
System.out.format("Give grade: %s%n", args[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do can either:

```
System.out.println("Give grade: " + args[0]);
```

or in C-like style:

```
System.out.printf("Give grade: %s%n", args[0]);
```

Comment: It's not like C, it is different even if the method name looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(String text);` internally calls [`PrintWriter#println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) method and it expect one argument.

You can concatenate those to String literals and passed it like below.

```
System.out.println("Give grade: " + args[0]);
```